# Upgrade from Drush6 to Drush 7 on OSX running Acquia Dev Desktop

Tags: macos, drupal, composer-php, drush, acquia

My question is really as it is stated in the title.

I use MacOSX and the Acquia Developer Desktop for running my Drupal sites that I develop locally.

I'd love to try out the new Drush 7, but I can't get it to 'upgrade' from Drush 6 to Drush 7.

I've tried:

1. cd into my /Applications/dev desktop
2. removing the drush folder
3. replacing it with a fresh .zip from GitHub

Ofcourse, when entering `"drush"` I get the message that I should have used Composer instead.

Installing with composer seems to work, but it doesn't install Drush 7 in my `Application/Dev Desktop(/drush)` folder, so it's of no use to me.

How do I force Composer to put drush in this specific directory? I get confused by all the configuration files and what to put in them. Is there something like `> composer install drush --right-here` ?

**EDIT**

After Clide's helpful answer, I get Drush version 7 running. I checked the version using "`drush version`".  However, when I try a real drush command ( `drush en -gmap`, in this case), I get the notorious "`Command pm-enable needs a higher bootstrap level to run`" error.

I invoke the command line from within the Acquia application, so the `PATH` should be correct. I also tried specifying the URI, and also that looks okay. I'll copy some of the output, if that helps.

```
 Drupal version         :  7.26                                                         
 Site URI               :  http://(sitename).local:8083                            
 PHP executable         :  /usr/local/bin/php                                           
 PHP configuration      :  /usr/local/etc/php/5.3/php.ini                               
 PHP OS                 :  Darwin                                                       
 Drush version          :  7.0-dev                                                      
 Drush temp directory   :  /tmp                                                         
 Drush configuration    :                                                               
 Drush alias files      :                                                               
 Drupal root            :  /Users/(myname)/Documents/(dev folder)/(sitename)
 Site path              :  sites/(sitename).local
```

Comment: `git clone https://github.com/drush-ops/drush.git drush; cd drush; composer install` should do it. Composer is used to install the libraries Drush needs, it doesn't fetch/download drush itself

Comment: Clive, thanks! That works. I realy couldn't have figured this out from the readme on GitHub. Why don't you write this as an answer, so I can give you the credit?

Comment: No worries, I've put that in :)

Comment: I'll mark it as 'the answer', although I haven't managed to get it running.

Comment: @Ideogram, Then why mark as answer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this context Composer is used to fetch the libraries Drush needs, it doesn't download Drush itself. Running the install process in the Drush root should do the trick:

```
git clone https://github.com/drush-ops/drush.git drush 
cd drush
composer install
```

and if you don't already have it

```
ln -s /path/to/drush/drush /usr/local/bin/drush # or wherever
```